# Tolerated Performance when generating a document from SQL

Tags: performance

Is it acceptable for a framework to generate an XLS document of more than 300k rows and 6 columns in 2 minutes?

This framework took 2 minutes to generate the document while fetching data from a local database (MySQL).

Should this framework be enhanced?

Comment: This depends entirely on the requirements of the framework's users.

Comment: I see.  So your requirement is that your library process data at least as fast as McAfee's Stringer x64?

Answer (score 4):

“Tolerable” depends not on your technical choices, but on the actual requirements as set forth by the users of your system. Depending on your users this may be perfectly fine, or may be a huge disruption in their workflow.

From a technical perspective, such long processing times indicate that you are doing some complicated processing, or making calls to external systems over the network, or that the way how you interact with the database is totally broken. If most of that time is spent in database queries this would seem rather unusual and could be investigated. E.g. do you have the proper indices on the database? Are you querying multiple records in bulk, or do you fetch one record at a time (e.g. because you are using an ORM inappropriately)?

But should you investigate this performance issue? That depends on the value of fixing this problem. Basically, if the cost of sticking with the slow solution is less than the cost of you spending time to investigate and fix this problem, then maybe this isn't great but it's still the better business decision.